# Python package for empirically estimating the ideal distribution

Tags: python, distribution

I have a data from the control-test matching output such as follows:

```
Drug        test_Ident  control_Ident   TRx_ctrl TRx_test   difference cohort
A                1      157267                  0     0      0          A
A               100     92594                   0     0      0          A
A               1000    134732                  0     0      0          B
A              10000    191899                  0     0      0          B
```

Here Trx_ctrl and trx_test are the number of prescriptions for a drug across test and control group. Here I want to study the distribution of difference in prescriptions(difference column) across test and control group.

But I want to empirically estimate that for which cohort which distribution would fit ideally( for the difference). For instance for cohort A Normal distribution would fit but for the other cohort some other distribution would fit. I am wondering if there exists a python package which can empirically infer that which distribution would fit for the respective cohort

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I was unable to find a package for empirically estimating the distribution of a parameter. Basically it should tell which distribution is ideal for the parameter across a strata.